How to perform a projection for a firestore query in react?
I'm trying to do a simple restriction and projection on a firestore Database. I came up with this:
import { getDocs, collection, query, where, select } from "firebase/firestore";

const userRef=collection(db, 'usertest')
const q=query(userRef, where('address','==','Tobago'), select("address"))
const querySS=await getDocs(q)

The where statement is working but the select is not with error TypeError: (0 , firebase_firestore__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.select) is not a function
Anyone knows how to get this working in firebase?

It's not possible using the web and mobile SDKs.  When you read a document, you always get the entire document.  The syntax you're showing with select only works with the backend Admin SDKs.  If you are trying to reduce the amount of data fetched from a single query, then you should consider splitting the data up into different collections, and query only the collection with the minimal data you need.

@DougStevenson thanks, I got it working. I used the backend admin sdk and it's working now
